# Error al reutilizar varibles

Tags: java, poo, variables, objeto, scanner

sigo con mis ejercicios en java y me encuentro que cuando quiero reutizar la variable ISBN para empezar a settear los datos del libro dos, cuando ejecuto, esa linea no me da opcion al scanner y me pide la siguiente variable.

```
/**
 * ProbarLibro.java
 * Programa para probar la clase Libro
 * ==================================
 * 
 * @author Luis Quesada Romero
 */

// Pertece al paquete tarea_libro

package tarea_libro;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProbarLibro { // Clase principal ProbarLibro

  public static void main(String[] args) { // Método Main

    // Varialbes

    String comenzamos;
    String respuestaSi = "s";
    String ISBN;
    String titulo;
    String autor;
    short paginas;

    // Inicio del programa

    System.out.println("BIENVENIDO\n");
    System.out.println("Este programa guarda los datos de dos libros y nos dira cual tiene más paginas");
    System.out.println("¿Comenzamos? s/n");

    // Guardamos la respuesta y la evaluamos para empezar o salir del programa
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    comenzamos = entrada.nextLine();

    if ( respuestaSi.equals(comenzamos) ) {

      // Se piden datos del primer libro y se instancia
      Libro libroUno = new Libro();

      // ISBN 1
      System.out.print("\nISBN del primer Libro: ");
      ISBN = entrada.nextLine();
      libroUno.setISBN(ISBN);

      // Titulo 1
      System.out.print("Título del primer Libro: ");
      titulo = entrada.nextLine();
      libroUno.setTitulo(titulo);

      // Autor 1
      System.out.print("Autor del primero Libro: ");
      autor = entrada.nextLine();
      libroUno.setAutor(autor);

      // Páginas 1
      System.out.print("Páginas del primer Libro: ");
      paginas = entrada.nextShort();
      libroUno.setPaginas(paginas);

      // Se piden los datos del segundo libro y se instancia
      Libro libroDos = new Libro();

      // ISBN 2
      System.out.print("\nISBN del segundo Libro: ");
      ISBN = entrada.nextLine();
      libroDos.setISBN(ISBN);

      // Título 2
      System.out.print("Título del segundo libro: ");
      titulo = entrada.nextLine();
      libroDos.setTitulo(titulo);

      // Autor 2
      System.out.print("Autor del segundo Libro: ");
      autor = entrada.nextLine();
      libroDos.setAutor(autor);

      // Páginas 2
      System.out.print("Págionas del segundo Libro: ");
      paginas = entrada.nextShort();
      libroDos.setPaginas(paginas);

    } else {
      System.out.println("Otra vez sera, buena suerte!");
    }

  } // Fin del método main

} // Fin de la clase pirncipal ProbarLibro
```

Os dejo tambien la clase libro por si el problema es de este archivo

```
/**
 * Libro.java
 * Definición de la clase Libro
 * ============================
 *
 *@author Luis Quesada Romero
 */

// Pertenece al paquete tarea_libro

package tarea_libro;

public class Libro { // Clase Libro

  // ATRIBUTOS //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  String ISBN;
  String titulo;
  String autor;
  short paginas;


  // MÉTODS /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  /**
   * Constuctores principal
   * ===================
   * 
   * @param ISBN
   * @param titulo
   * @param autor
   * @param paginas
   */

  public Libro (String ISBN, String titulo, String autor, short paginas){
    this.ISBN = ISBN;
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.autor = autor;
    this.paginas = paginas;
  }

  public Libro() {

  }


  /*
   * Metodos Getter
   */

  public String getISBN() {
    return ISBN;
  }

  public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
  }

  public String getAutor() {
    return autor;
  }

  public short getPaginas() {
    return paginas;
  }


  /*
   * Métodos Setter
   */

  public void setISBN(String ISBN) {
    this.ISBN = ISBN;
  }

  public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
  }

  public void setAutor(String autor) {
    this.autor = autor;
  }

  public void setPaginas(short paginas) {
    this.paginas = paginas;
  }

} // Fin de la clase Libro
```

Como os digo setteo bien el libro uno, pero al empezar con los datos del libro dos, el primer dato que pido del libro dos no me da la opcion de introducirlos, me salta directamente al segundo dato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El metodo nextShort() avanza en la misma linea, por lo que para poder avanzar a la siguiente linea despues de utilizarlo debes utilizar el metodo nextLine().

Ejemplo:

```
// ...

// Páginas 1
System.out.print("Páginas del primer Libro: ");
paginas = entrada.nextShort();
libroUno.setPaginas(paginas);

// Avanzas a la siguiente linea
entrada.nextLine();

// Se piden los datos del segundo libro y se instancia
Libro libroDos = new Libro();

// ISBN 2
System.out.print("\nISBN del segundo Libro: ");
ISBN = entrada.nextLine();
libroDos.setISBN(ISBN);

// ...
```

#### Actualizacion

Tienes velo como si Scanner estuviera leyendo un archivo linea por linea. nextLine avanza atravez de las lineas y nextShort() y nextInt() a travez de los valores numericos de cada linea.

Ej:

```
linea 1 | 1 2 3
linea 2 | Hola Mundo
linea 3 | 1425
linea 4 | a
```

En la primera linea para avanzar entre los numero que tiene, tienes que utilizar nextInt(). Y para avanzar a la siguiente linea, donde esta "Hola Mundo", tienes que utilizar nextLine().

```
linea 1 | 1          2          3
          ^          ^          ^
          nextInt()  nextInt()  nextInt()  nextLine()

linea 2 | Hola Mundo                       nextLine()
linea 3 | 1425
          ^
          nextInt()                        nextLine()

linea 4 | a                                nextLine()
```

`nextInt()` obtiene el valor numérico y avanza al siguiente valor.
`nextLine()` obtiene el valor de la linea y avanza a la siguiente linea.

Comment: Entonces si le pido al usuario que me de vario short, tengo que usar: entrada.nextLine();
Para que me lea el siguiente short?

Si lo hago con int pasa lo mismo, es que veo algo raro esto, o no me queda claro su funcionamiento

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta, mirala.

Comment: Perfecto entendido, después de ver la explicación queda claro, ademas quedaba implicito y no me di cuenta:
nextLine - siguiente linea
nextInt - siguiente entero
nextShort -siguiente short

Answer (score 2):

Probablemente es porque tu estas leyendo un short antes y este no consume el salto de linea solo consume el numero ejemplo si en paginas pusiste 80 esta leyendo "80" pero se queda "\n" eso se queda en el scanner y por eso no te pide el  ISBN porque interpreta el "\n" que quedo como si esa fuera tu respuesta.
Para solucionarlo solo pon un next line antes de leer tu ISBN

```
     String saltoDeLinea = scan.nextLine();
```